# Can't make float:left work on horizontal ul

Tags: html, css

I've just finished a CSS3 class and I want to use what I've learned on my website. I want a horizontal bar across the top of the page with two images and some text between them, centered in the page. The problem is that I can't seem to get the `float:left` to work on the `<li>` elements.

I'll be using the same technique to put a menu below this bar. This is just the beginning of this page and may not even be the best design, I'm just trying to use in the real world what I learned in class a step at a time.

I'm trying to stay away from using classes everywhere in the HTML code, that's a lot of trouble in maintenance and changing things.

See [my website](http://pixelmeow.com).

Here's the HTML:

```
<div>
    <ul id="topBar" class="clearfix">
        <li><img src="../../images/heinleinmedalgold-glow150.jpg" /></li>
        <li id="logo">pixelmeow's pages</li>
        <li><img src="../../images/heart_grenade.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
@import url(reset.css);
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
    content:" ";
    display:table;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear:both;
}
body {
    width:100%;
}
#topBar {
    width:100%;
    height:10em;
    background-color:black;
}
#topBar ul {
    margin:0 auto;
}
#topBar ul li {
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    border:2px solid red;
    height:5em;
    display:inline-block;
}
#topBar ul li:first-child {
    text-align:right;
}
#topBar ul li:nth-of-type(2) {
    min-width:40%;
    padding-top:5em;
    text-align:center;
}
#topBar ul li:last-child {
    text-align:left
}
#logo {
    font-family:kells_uncialbold;
    color:gray;
    top: 50px;

}
```

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that a list here is probably not the best choice for layout. Also, you might have trouble centering when using floats.

Comment: See - http://jsfiddle.net/hsf627k9/2/

Comment: That fiddle worked beautifully! Thank you! That's a wonderful markup, it's got the right responsiveness I wanted when the browser is smaller. I've got some ideas about the menubar now, but I'm wondering if that will line up as well, too. I'd love to give this an upvote, but the existing answer works on the original `<ul>` question. If you make this an answer, I'll give it an upvote because I do love it! edit: forgot to tag you, @Paulie_D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selectors are incorrect. `#topBar ul li` should be `#topBar li`. What you have tries to select a `<ul>` that's a descendant of an element with the ID of `topBar`, when in reality it *is* the element with that ID. So you could use either `#topBar li` or `ul#topBar li`.

```css
@import url(reset.css);
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
    content:" ";
    display:table;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear:both;
}
body {
    width:100%;
}
#topBar {
    width:100%;
    height:10em;
    background-color:black;
}
#topBar {
    margin:0 auto;
}
#topBar li {
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    border:2px solid red;
    height:5em;
    display:inline-block;
}
#topBar li:first-child {
    text-align:right;
}
#topBar li:nth-of-type(2) {
    min-width:40%;
    padding-top:5em;
    text-align:center;
}
#topBar li:last-child {
    text-align:left
}
#logo {
    font-family:kells_uncialbold;
    color:gray;
    top: 50px;

}
```

```html
<div>
    <ul id="topBar" class="clearfix">
        <li><img src="http://pixelmeow.com/images/heinleinmedalgold-glow150.jpg" /></li>
        <li id="logo">pixelmeow's pages</li>
        <li><img src="http://pixelmeow.com/images/heart_grenade.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `ul#topbar` did the trick. I should use that with the links when I put them up so that the colors stay across the whole `<li>` as the browser gets smaller. I'm trying to make this responsive, following the way we built a page in the course. Thank you so much for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

It's probably worth mentioning that a list here is probably not the best choice for layout. Also, you might have trouble centering when using floats.

[JSfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hsf627k9/2/)

```css
div#topbar {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
div#topbar img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#logo {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="topbar">
  <img src="http://pixelmeow.com/images/heinleinmedalgold-glow150.jpg" />
  <h1 id="logo">pixelmeow's pages</h1>

  <img src="http://pixelmeow.com/images/heart_grenade.jpg" />
</div>
```